# How to setup GPIO on a Flask production server?

Tags: gpio, python, web-server, apache-httpd

I am coding a web application with Flask and I come across with a problem where I cannot setup my gpios on my public production server. It throw an error `500 Internal server error`. I've realized recently, when I remove `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)`from code then the error disappears. On my development server this issue does not occur. How can I run my GPIO on production? This problem come from WSGI?

The code where I invoke GPIO looks like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
""" GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT) """


import AdminPanel.views
```

The error occurs when I remove commented part where is `setup()` function.

Comment: permissions issue? Is the prod server running as a non root user (which is typical)?   Getting any helpful errors from the python code(not just the returned error in the browers or whereever your attempting to make the call to the server)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. The problem is that there is no error from python code. I run it with debug mode but this mode works apparently only when run app on localhost, by the way this bugs shows only on browser screen, not in my terminal.  Do you know how can I catch these errors another way? How can I run prod server as a root user?

Comment: Well, you dont want to run the server as root if its going to be accessible from the outside. What I would do, is create the smallest program you can that shows this error. Simple server with the setmode() call in the same place you have it now, remove all extra code, so its the simplest it can be while still showing the issue. And then edit your question to include the code. This way we can see exactly what you are trying. This will allow someone to try and reproduce your error and find a fix, or be able to spot the issue in the code. Its hard to find a solution off a description of the code

Comment: Ok so I have added part of code where the error is coming from.

Comment: I've tried with chmod and sudo flask run to get permission but nothing works properly... Why server is always broking down when I invoke setup() function??